# Updating to Danish

Tags: software-installation, language-support

Installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 Today.
All of it.
Takes forever.
Playing a little around - it is slower than the Windoze Vista that was the previous OS.

Tried to change language to dansih.
Works in FF.
Then theres an options (in Settings - language and something...), to change system-language to Danish in two places.

"You need to reboot"...
It just never comes back in a usefull state - looks like keyboard and mouse are directly tied to graphics driver - screen colours and patterns are changing with every karacter typed or moving the mouse

(occatinally actually dansih word, at random places on the screen.)

Answer (score 1):

You can install a new language via the *Language Support* GUI. You can access it either through the *Manage Installed Languages* button in *Settings -> Region & Language* or through the terminal command

```
gnome-language-selector
```

Comment: At the monet, I have a screen that I can see nothing at all on.
I have tried reinstalling from scratch - and it gives the same results.
So no , I can do shit - and it actually looks like the language is not the problem - it just manifested at the same time, that I tried to switch.

Comment: @BirgerSørensen: Sorry to hear that. Then you may want to submit a new question about the main problem.